# ruby hash as first element of array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm parsing JSON from an API. I have a `foo` element that's a hash sometimes, and an array of hashes, other times.

```
foo: { ... }

foo: [
  { ... },
  { ... }
]
```

I'd like to just use `Array(foo)` to always get the an array with at least the one element, but it converts the hash to `[[..., ...], [..., ...]]`. Is there an elegant way to handle this, besides using `foo.is_a?(Hash/Array)`?

Comment: Considering that you do not have a Rails tag, why would you want to load something as massive as `ActiveSupport` to perform a simple calculation? There's nothing simpler than the way @Veet does it. Even if the lack of a Rails tag was an oversight, you cannot very well add it now.

Comment: @CarySwoveland correct. This is in a gem, so ruby only. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to @yez answer, if you are not using `activesupport`, you can extend `Array` to have a `wrap` function:

```
def Array.wrap(object)
  if object.nil?
    []
  elsif object.respond_to?(:to_ary)
    object.to_ary || [object]
  else
    [object]
  end
end
```

Copied from http://apidock.com/rails/Array/wrap/class

Another crude way to implement it is:

```
def Array.wrap(object)
  return [] if object.nil?
  [object].flatten(1)
end
```

Comment: You should use `flatten(1)` to avoid flattening nested arrays.

Comment: Yes, but the question has no Rails tag, so a pure-Ruby solution solution is of principle interest.

Answer (score 3):

In a Rails environment, with access to `activesupport`:

You could use `Array.wrap`

```
foo = { a: :b }
=> {:a=>:b}
Array.wrap(foo)
=> [{:a=>:b}]
Array.wrap([1,2,3])
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Without Rails, you could do `gem install activesupport` and then in your code: `require 'activesupport'`

Comment: gem install activesupport; require activesupport

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve it using plain Ruby then you can push the item(s) (either Array of Hashes or Hash) to an empty array and then flatten the array like following:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > [{a:1}].flatten(1)
 => [{:a=>1}] 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > [[{a:1},{b:2}]].flatten(1)
 => [{:a=>1}, {:b=>2}]
```

i.e. `[foo].flatten(1)` should work.

Comment: You don't need `push`, just: `[{a:1}].flatten` / `[[{a:1},{b:2}]].flatten`

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your input. The answer above should suffice what Dudo is asking for without even using active support. i.e. he gets the foo element as a hash or as an array of hashes and he wants to convert it to an array of hash or an array of hashes.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `[].push(obj)` is equivalent to `[obj]`

Comment: Got your point. [foo].flatten should work. Edited the answer.

Comment: This is the best answer, imo, short and sweet and pure-Ruby, as called for by the question. You could also write `[*[obj]]`; e.g., `[*[{a:1}]] #=> [{:a=>1}]`, `[*[{a:1, b:2}]] #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]`.